# Can somebody teach me how to reset the menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, submenu

```
var lastid;
function show_submenu(obj) {
    var ele = document.getElementById(obj).style;
    var elemLastId = document.getElementById(lastid);
    if (elemLastId != null) {
        elemLastId.style.display = "none";
    }
    lastid = obj;
    if (ele.display == "none") {
        ele.display = "block";
    } else {
        ele.display = "none";
    }
}

function toggle_menu(id){
    var menu = document.getElementById(id);
    if(menu.style.display == 'none')
        menu.style.display = 'block';
    else
        menu.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Can somebody teach me how to debug this code?

I want to reset the main level when I click the button of menu again.

[image: Current step]

[image: Correct step]

Comment: <nav>
<div id="menu_btn" onClick="toggle_menu('container');"><a>MENU</a></div>
<div id="container" style="display: none;">
<span class="M1" onclick="show_submenu('S1')"><a href="#">M1</a></span>
<div id="S1" style="display: none;">
 <span class="S1-1"><a href="#">S1-1</a></span>
<span class="S1-2"><a href="#">S1-2</a></span>
<span class="S1-3"><a href="#">S1-3</a></span>
</div>
</div>
</nav>

Comment: I cant replicate the code, try remaking it in http://jsfiddle.net/ and paste the URL. Then we can have a go at fixing it